# Find the supplier name who supplies all the part of a particular color

Tags: database, set-operations

I have the following tables:

Suppliers(Sno, Sname, Address)
Parts(Pno, Pname, Colour)
Catalogue(Sno, Pno, Price)

I want to find the name of all suppliers who is supplying all the parts of a particular color say "BLUE"?

I want to solve it using logical operators like AND, OR, NOT etc and select, project or join operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM    Catalogue AS C
        INNER JOIN Parts AS P
            ON C.Pno = P.Pno
        INNER JOIN Suppliers AS S
            ON C.Sno = S.Sno
WHERE   P.Color = 'Blue'
```

Hope it helps.